# SQL Server : error converting data type nvarchar to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

**EDIT**
*Thank you for all your help.*

First thing, I have read tons of post and question of people having this same error, mines varies for `int` and `bigint` but the error stays the same, I can not insert or update. I am working with Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Management Studio  and I've having this problem for the last two to three days, I know there are tons of answers I just don't know the F is wrong.

This is my stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myproc]
    (@name VARCHAR(50),
     @ID BIGINT,
     @birthdate DATETIME,
     @Enabled BIT,
     @married BIT,
     @employees INT,
     @hiredDate DATETIME)
AS
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)       
    SET @sql ='IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyTable.ID ='+@ID+')
                     UPDATE MyTable
                     SET
                     name ='+@name+'
                    ,birthdate='+@birthdate+'
                    ,Enabled ='+@Enabled+'
                    ,married='+@married+'
                    ,employees='+@employees+'
                    ,hiredDate='+@hiredDate+'
                    where ID = '+@ID+'
                ELSE
                INSERT INTO MyTable(name,ID,birthdate,Enabled,married,employees,hiredDate)VALUES(
                '+@name+','+@ID+','+convert(varchar,@birthdate,20)+','+@Enabled+','+@married+','+@employees+','+convert(varchar,@hiredDate,20)+')'

    EXEC (@SQL)
END
```

I am sick of this damn error and I am losing it.

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure testinsert, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Error converting data type varchar to datetime.

I made this little table just so i could ask and try to make this trial

I run this stored procedure with:

```
DECLARE @return_value INT

EXEC @return_value = testinsert
        @name = 'asd',
        @ID = 25,
        @birthdate = '2018-12-10 16 45 00',
        @Enabled = 1,
        @married = NULL,
        @employees = NULL,
        @hiredDate = NULL

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

Table:

```
[dbo].[MYDTABLE]
           ([name]
           ,[ID]
           ,[birthdate]
           ,[Enabled]
           ,[married]
           ,[employees]
           ,[hiredDate])
     VALUES
           (<name, varchar(50),>
           ,<ID, bigint,>
           ,<birthdate, datetime,>
           ,<Enabled, bit,>
           ,<married, bit,>
           ,<employees, int,>
           ,<hiredDate, datetime,>)
GO
```

Comment: Use `sp_executesql` and pass the values in as parameters.  Then you won't have type problems with dynamic SQL.  It is unclear why you are using dynamic SQL here in the first place.  This looks like regular SQL -- in fact, regular SQL that might be replaced with a single `MERGE` statement.

Comment: Why are you using dynamic sql here? There is absolutely no need it from what you posted. And your code is wide open to sql injection because you just build up a string and execute it. That defeats the advantage of passing in parameters in the first place.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I want to enter the table as a parameter, but if this does not work, how can i expect it to work with a variable? and I tried the implicit way and i get what I think is the same error but the implicit version of it.

Comment: @Zealot91 . . . If the table needs to be a parameter, then munge the query string with the table name, but pass everything else in as a parameter.

Comment: And you can still use parameters even with dynamic sql if you use sp_executesql, just not the table name. You would need to wrap that in QUOTENAME though to help mitigate sql injection.

Comment: @Sean Lange But then I just get:
'Implicit conversion from data type datetime to bigint is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.'

Comment: Can you share that code? If you are parameterizing your dynamic sql that shouldn't be happening, unless you have parameters crossed.

Comment: @SeanLange Sorry but for the implicit way i cant. i am trying to figure out why i get this error for this particular way to do it.

Comment: The way you are trying to do it here you really don't want to fix. You want to use sp_executesql. I will post an example here shortly so you czn see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are trying to pass in table name (not in your question but mentioned in the comments) you do need dynamic sql because table names cannot be parameterized. However, you can pass in the name as a parameter to your procedure just like all the values. Then you can parameterize your dynamic sql which will eliminate all the hassle of datatype conversions and such. Something like this should be pretty close. I also added a lot of white space so this is easier to read.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myproc]
(    
    @name varchar(50)
    , @ID bigint
    , @birthdate datetime
    , @Enabled bit
    , @married bit 
    , @employees int
    , @hiredDate datetime
    , @TableName sysname
)
AS
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)       
    SET @sql = 'IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ' WHERE ID = @ID )
                     UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ' 
                     SET
                     name = @name
                    , birthdate = @birthdate
                    , Enabled = @Enabled
                    , married = @married
                    , employees = @employees
                    , hiredDate = @hiredDate
                    where ID = @ID
                ELSE
                INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + '
                (
                    name
                    , ID
                    , birthdate
                    , Enabled
                    , married
                    , employees
                    , hiredDate
                )VALUES
                (
                    @name
                    , @ID
                    , @birthdate
                    , @Enabled
                    , @married
                    , @employees
                    , @hiredDate
                )'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
    N'@name varchar(50)
    , @ID bigint
    , @birthdate datetime
    , @Enabled bit
    , @married bit 
    , @employees int
    , @hiredDate datetime'
    , @name = @name 
    , @ID = @ID
    , @birthdate = @birthdate
    , @Enabled = @Enabled
    , @married = @married
    , @employees = @employees
    , @hiredDate = @hiredDate

END
```

Comment: Yes, this will work. But I see antipattern here. Each table will have same structure so it looks like table per date/customer/....

Comment: @LukaszSzozda what do you mean that it is a table per date/customer? This seems like what the OP has. Not a good way to model data for sure.

Comment: Sorry but I still get the same error I have been dealing with so far:
`
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure dbo.myproc, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 0]
Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.`

Comment: @SeanLange It is common scenario [SELECT * FROM sales + @yymm](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Sales_yymm) where you have the same structure over multiple tables. I provided table per date as an example. Nothing specific with OPs scenario.

Comment: If there are table that have the date in the name that is the problem. And yes that is an anti-pattern for sure. Anytime you find yourself needing to pass in the table name to run the same query it is a clear sign the design phase when wrong.

Comment: That error must be something in your data. Assuming you provided the correct datatype that won't happen in this code. Can you share the **exact** code you call this with?

Comment: @SeanLange I did, I edited the answer and added the execution into the question and i am going to add the table structure(sort of)

Comment: The string you are testing with is the problem. "'2018-12-10 16 45 00'" is NOT a valid date string. Try this instead. "2018-12-10 16:45:00"

Comment: @SeanLange IT WORKED, I had to delete the ,20 in the values "statement" for it was giving me a error for too many parameters in my insert than declared. what was that 20 for? date format?

Comment: Oops...yes that was a carry over from your original stuff that I copy and pasted. I will edit this to remove that.

Comment: I dont get it, now it works with the date with or without double quotes, I am confused, works with simple quotes and souble quotes. Anyhow Thanks for your help, and everyone else.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for dynamic SQL at all:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myproc]
(    
    @name varchar(50),@ID bigint,@birthdate datetime,@Enabled bit
    ,@married bit ,@employees int,@hiredDate datetime
)
AS
BEGIN 
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyTable.ID =@id)
     UPDATE MyTable
     SET name =name
        ,birthdate=@birthdate
        ,Enabled =@Enabled
        ,married=@married
        ,employees=@employees
        ,hiredDate=@hiredDate
      where ID = @ID;
 ELSE
INSERT INTO MyTable(name,ID,birthdate,Enabled,married,employees,hiredDate)
VALUES(@name, @ID, @birthdate, @Enabled, @married, @employees, @hiredDate) ;      
END
```

**EDIT:**

> I run this sp with:
>
> ```
>     @birthdate = '2018-12-10 16 45 00',
> ```

I propose to provide parameter with culture independent format ISO-8601 `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss`

```
 @birthdate = '2018-12-10T16:45:00',
```

Comment: i want to give the table as a parameter, but if this does not work, how will i make it work with the parameter?

Comment: @Zealot91 Then make dynamic query  and concatenate table_name after sanitation with `QUOTENAME` but provide rest of parameters using `sp_executesql`

Comment: I tried the implicit way and got Implicit conversion from data type datetime to bigint is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
that is the same error in a way.

Comment: Also, i get the same error with your answer:
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure testinsert, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 0]
Error converting data type varchar to datetime.

Comment: @Zealot91 How do you call stored procedure? Please pass `EXEC [dbo].[myproc] ..., @birthdate = '20180101', ...` With culture independent date literal.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was because you didn't convert the data, your fixed script below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myproc]
    (@name VARCHAR(50),
     @ID BIGINT,
     @birthdate DATETIME,
     @Enabled BIT,
     @married BIT,
     @employees INT,
     @hiredDate DATETIME)
AS
AS
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)       
    SET @sql ='IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyTable.ID ='+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@ID)+')
                     UPDATE MyTable
                     SET
                     name ='''+@name+'''
                    ,birthdate=CONVERT(DATETIME,'''+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@birthdate,20)+''',20)
                    ,Enabled ='+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@Enabled)+'
                    ,married='+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@married)+'
                    ,employees='+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@employees)+'
                    ,hiredDate=CONVERT(DATETIME,'''+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@hiredDate,20)+''',20)
                    where ID = '+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@ID)+'
                ELSE
                INSERT INTO MyTable(name,ID,birthdate,Enabled,married,employees,hiredDate)VALUES(
                '''+@name+''','+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@ID)+',CONVERT(DATETIME,'''+convert(varchar,@birthdate,20)+''',20),'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@Enabled)+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@married)+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@employees)+',CONVERT(DATETIME,'''+convert(varchar,@hiredDate,20)+''',20))'
PRINT (@SQL)

END
GO
```

Comment: I still get the same error I dont know if I am converting wrong or what.:


Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure dbo.myproc, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 0]
Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.

Comment: I've created a table based in the parameters of your procedure and it worked here, how did you create your table ?

Comment: I shared the table in the question :)